# How to alphabetically sort a JQuery UI sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I was wondering if it is possible to have a JQuery UI sortable default to be alphabetically sorted.  If so, is it also possible to keep it alphabetically sorted in real time if I add items to the sortable?  Below is my code:

```
// Adds item to sortable list
$(".addButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // set var item to be the string inputted by the user
    var item = $("input[name='brewItem']").val();
    // parses input string, splitting at commas into liArray containing substrings as elements
    var liArray = item.split(", ");
    // for loop to add each brew to the sortable list (length-1 because last element in array is empty string)
    for (var i = 0; i < liArray.length-1; i++) {
        // sets var $li to the string in the ith index of liArray
        var $li = $("<li class='ui-state-default'/>").text(liArray[i]);



        // adds var $li to gui
        $("#sortable").append($li);
    };
    // refreshes the page so var $li shows up
    $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
});
```

I'm not quite sure where or how to implement this.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to tweak it to make it sort as you need.

Try this:- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phd2vp33/)

Use custom sort method

```
 function sort() {
    var sortableList = $('#sortable');
    var listitems = $('li', sortableList);

    listitems.sort(function (a, b) {

        return ($(a).text().toUpperCase() > $(b).text().toUpperCase())  ? 1 : -1;
    });
    sortableList.append(listitems);

}
```

Call it in your sortable's create event `Create` and in  Button Click

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        sort();
    }
});
```

Or Extend jquery ui sortable widget to include your custom sorting logic.

Comment: It seems  that this function will only work if the list has 13 or fewer items in it because **"Comparing two strings with > returns a boolean, but sort expects a number."** See --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246809/alphabetically-sort-elements-in-sortable-list-with-over-13-items#28246860

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thank you, i never knew i had written this, it was a long while back. Though i am not using localecompare because it will be inappropriate for me to update it considering the linked answer in your comment i am now returning number.

Comment: No problem, and thank you for the function in the first place, couldn't have gotten mine going without your answer to guide  me

Comment: No, infact Thank you!! :) i would not have realized mistake in my old answer.. :D

Answer (score 0):

instantiate sortable

```
var $sortable =$("#sortable").sortable(options);
```

don't overwhelm the browser with unnecessary access to the dom

before event handler, cache your input

```
var $brew=$("input[name='brewItem']");
```

optimize your appending by creating a html string

you can use join & do it in a line in your handler

```
$('<li>'+ $brew.val().split(", ").join('</li><li>')+'</li>').appendTo($sortable) ;
```

nb : perf would be better is the li set was wrapped, but in your case you'd need to unwrap after... can't say which would be faster

```
$sortable.sortable('refresh')
```